# Use CKeditor in template with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, angularjs-ng-template

I have a problem to use CKeditor.

First in the top I have this :

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="test"></textarea>
```

No problem I have a textarea with the buttons style (bold,underline,...) of ckeditor.

But I have the same texterea in a template :

```
<script type="text/ng-template".....
.....
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="test"></textarea>
.....
.....</script>
```

And I have a simple textarea... Do you know this problem ?

Comment: How/where do you init the ckeditors? Probably with jQuery? The ng-templates are loaded in asynchronously, so **after** the ckeditors are initialized by jquery

Comment: Yes you right, do you think there is a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, create a simple directive or use [existing libraries](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use directives for this, because angular loads in templates asynchronously while the ckeditors are created (by jquery probably) when the document is loaded.

Either use an existing library, like https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor, or create a simple directive yourself:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("ckeditor", [function(){
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                CKEDITOR.replace(elem[0], {
                    // configuration
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

html:

```
<textarea ckeditor></textarea>
```